# Htaccess rewrite top domain in Joomla based on language

Tags: apache, .htaccess, joomla, cross-domain, joomfish

I've a mysite.it with joomla, the site is in /home subdirectory, in the root / there's an htaccess with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ home/index.php [L]` so the /home is hidden.
I've also joomfish installed for a secondary (en) language, modrewrite on and no friendly url.
I've also bought a secondary mysite.us and it now simply redirects to the english joomsifh-managed lannguage.
SO ;) what I want to do, if possible is sorta like:
if language detected is english, rewrite mysite.it with mysite.us (and please don't touch the joomlish ulr ;) )

is that clear? any idea from any htaccess master? :-)

p.s.
I'm on my own linux vps server and joomla 1.5.26

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`

```
# If prefered language contains english ...
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} en
# and if accessing .it domain
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} .*it$
RewriteRule /(.*) http://mysite.us/$1 [R,L]
```

`

Comment: I tried to put this in the htacces in /home that's the joomla default one but it brokes my site's css and the url stays at .it, do I need to put it in the domain root's htacces that contains the code written in my post?